# Alamofire not sending request properly

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

so heres my case
i have a list of `parameters`

```
let body: Parameters = [
        "name": "Sample Name"]
```

and i am sending this body variable like this using `alamofire`:

```
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL",method: .post,parameters: body,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseData { response in
   debugPrint("All Response Info: \(response)")
   //printing the body just to see what it is sending and everything is as it should be
   print(body)

   if let data = response.result.value, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
   print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
}
 }
```

the problem is the response is a `400 bad request` response with an error message `name is required`.which is required in the `api` but for some reasong `alamofire` is not sending it properly i guess.why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe your api accepts parameters in body so you need to use `encoding:.body` in request function

Answer (score 0):

Depending on API documentation you might want to change the encoding type to URLEncoding like so: -

```
URLEncoding.default
```

Comment: I tried that its the same result but the documentation also says to use JSONEncoding.default  for encoding json format

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `responseData`, try `responseJSON`

```
Alamofire.request("BASE_URL", method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: 
  JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

}
```